# Get data from two tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i am trying to execute query to get data from table 1 and apply where clause on table 2
this is a sample query to execute on Code-igniter

```
 SELECT * FROM table1,table2 WHERE `hide` = 0 AND `reject` = 0 AND `disable` = 0 AND `private` = 0 AND `table2`.`wepay_account_id` != '' ORDER BY `table1_id` DESC LIMIT 40
```

this query execute in database but not execute in code-igniter

i am trying this code in model

```
 $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->where('hide', 0);
        $this->db->where('reject', 0);
        $this->db->where('disable', 0);
        $this->db->where('private', 0);
        $this->db->where('table2.wepay_account_id !=',"");
        $this->db->from('table1','table2');
        $this->db->order_by('table1', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $a=$this->db->last_query();
        print_r($a);
        exit;
```

but i am facing this error

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'table2.wepay_account_id' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`table1`) WHERE `hide` = 0 AND `reject` = 0 AND `disable` = 0 AND `private` = 0 AND `table2`.`wepay_account_id` != '' ORDER BY `table1_id` DESC LIMIT 40
```

Comment: Plz, give us the two table's schema.

Comment: secema is not issue.... $this->db->from('table1','table2'); when query execute table2 is not show.. look error SELECT *  FROM (`table1`).. table2 is missing

Comment: where is the select statement? I mean ``$this->db->select('table1.SOMETHING, table2.SOMETHING');``

Comment: error says `wepay_account_id`  is not  present in `table2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code segment Select use for `table1`. There is no `table2`

Its not posisble add where condition as `table2`.`wepay_account_id`

Use this join(),

```
 $this->db->from('table1');
 $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id')
```

Comment: You have to use table2 as a main table or join table other wise you can't access like this

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$this->db->from('table1','table2');
```

with

```
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2','true');
```

This will be equillent to your simple mysql query.